# What is the best setting for this workstation to speed up VASP calculations?

Tags: vasp, high-performance-computing

I am working on HP workstation with :

- 128 GB of RAM
- INTEL(R) XEON E5-2620 V3 with 12 cores

What are the best settings of `NCORE`, `KPAR`, etc. to speed up calculations on this computer?

Comment: I am not a VASP user but I would guess that the optimal parallelization scheme also depends on each calculation you want to perform.

Comment: kindly check this link which contain benchmarking link for vasp https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4525/how-to-set-ncore-kpar-and-nbands-to-speed-up-calculations-on-vasp/4529#4529

Comment: Use Intel compilers, they are the best on Intel processors.

Comment: This question is currently being discussed in the [VASP chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57466300#57466300).

Comment: I think this would constitute a duplicate of the question linked by pranav kumar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to choose these parameters is dependent on your system, which may need to test to find the most optimized computational strategy.

Here is a good tutorial to talk about these setting: https://www.nsc.liu.se/support/Events/VASP_workshop_2020/seminar3.pdf

- NCORE:

[image]

- NPAR:
- [image]
- KPAR:

[image]

Comment: I expect this question will be closed as a duplicate. You can leave your answer here, but it may be more visible if you move it to the question linked by pranav kumar.

Comment: @Tyberius You mean I should put this answer to that post that Pranav Kumar linked? :)